# Asp.Net MVC - How can I save ModelState for ChildAction?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have post action there is usual code like

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View("Edit", viewModel);
}
```

in Edit view I call Action that generates PartialView

```
@Html.Action("GetFields","Field", new {Id = Model.Id})
```

My action

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult GetFields(int? Id)
{
...
}
```

In this action `ModelState` is new, it differences from `ModelState` in post action

Is there way to store `ModelState` between action and his child action?

(I know that I can use `TempData` (currently I use it in project) and so on for storing this info, I want to know if another way exists, I mean if framework includes ready solution or oportunity to get access through the fields)

**UPDATE**

ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.ViewData.ModelState return ModelState for post action

Comment: I'm able to get access only to ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext with this

Comment: I've got a feeling that you are trying to do something that framework is not meant to do. Why do you need access to `ModelState` in partial? can you not pass required data stored into the child action?

Comment: I don't want to access it I want that validation messages displays for PartialView, looks like, that I have to pass data by another way and then add it to ModelState of child action. Are you sure that it posible only by this way?

Comment: No, not sure if you can or cannot do what you want. But I'm sure there will be another, probably easier way to get the same result. Perhaps if you tell us why you want this to happen, people will be able to suggest other ways to get required outcome.

Comment: @trailmax, the esieast way for me is using temp data and currently I use it in project, but if framework allows to make it without this additional own code I want to know it. Thank you for your interesting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it impossible to do without copying.

I can get access to ModelState with this,

```
this.ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.ViewData.ModelState;
```

Object `ViewData` contains a lot from parent action, but what about ModelState?

It contains new ModelState. It even doesn't have setter. From source

```
 public class ViewDataDictionary : IDictionary<string, object>
 {
    private readonly ModelStateDictionary _modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();

 public ModelStateDictionary ModelState
 {
     get { return _modelState; }
 }
```

Other fields like Model, ModelMetadata and so on are setted with value from parent controller, for ModelState creates key-value pair in constructo only for this action, that use it, not from parent.